# Why mouseover and mouseout is not working properly in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button

```
<button onmouseover="Lobby()" class="menuBtn"> Lobby </button>
```

then I have a Lobby()

```
function Lobby()
    {
        document.getElementById("lobby").style.display = "block";
    }
```

and then I have a style

```
#lobby
{
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 16%;
}
```

I have a div

```
<div onmouseout="HideLobby()" class="submenupanel" id="lobby">
        <button onclick="" class="l">Lobby</button>
        <button onclick="GoToHelpDesk()" class="l">Information Center</button>
        <button onclick="ProductDisplay()" class="l">Product Display</button>
    </div>
```

Another Function

```
function HideLobby()
    {
        document.getElementById("lobby").style.display = "none";
    }
```

So When I hover to Lobby Button its showing div as it should. And when I remove my mouse from div its hiding as it should. But when I hover on `Information Center` or `Product Display` div is hiding. Why?

Comment: because you have written the HideLobby function on whole div

Comment: There are `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onmouseleave` instead `onmouseout`

> The mouseout event triggers when the mouse pointer leaves any child
>   elements as well the selected element.
>
> The mouseleave event is only triggered when the mouse pointer leaves
>   the selected element.

```js
function Lobby() {
  document.getElementById("lobby").style.display = "block";
}

function HideLobby(event) {
  document.getElementById("lobby").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#lobby {
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 16%;
}
```

```html
<button onmouseover="Lobby()" class="menuBtn"> Lobby </button>

<div onmouseleave="HideLobby()" class="submenupanel" id="lobby">
  <button onclick="" class="l">Lobby</button>
  <button onclick="GoToHelpDesk()" class="l">Information Center</button>
  <button onclick="ProductDisplay()" class="l">Product Display</button>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help